# Determine $\int f\; d\lambda^2$ for a measurable function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, indefinite-integrals

Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2}),\lambda^2)$ and let $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$
where

$$f_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}1_{B_n}$$
and $B_n=\left [-1/n^2,1/n^2 \right )\times \left [ -\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n} \right ), n\geq 1$.

- Determine $\int f\; d\lambda^2$

---

I have shown that the function $f$ is an element in $\mathcal{M}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}}^+(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2))$ but I am unsure on how to continue from this point (knowing that it can be determined from it being an element in the given set). How do I determine such a integral from this point?

Comment: do you know how the Lebesgue integral is constructed? And have you heard of the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @lmaosome We have constructed it with finite real-linear combinations of indicator functions. I have heard of DCT yes but not comfortable with it fully!

Comment: then you know how to compute $\int f_n\,\mathrm d\lambda^2$. If you can show that your function hat hand satisfies the requirements of DCT, you are done. (I think monotone convergence theorem may suffice already

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming $\lambda^2$ is the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure.)

The $f_n$ are positive functions, therefore $g_N := \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{f_n}$ are positive functions, increasing in n.
Hence the Monotone Convergence Theorem yields
$$
\int{f(x) \, \, \lambda^2(dx)}
= \int{\lim_{N \to \infty} g_N(x) \, \, \lambda^2(dx)}
= \lim_{N \to \infty} \int{ g_N(x) \, \, \lambda^2(dx)}.
$$
For each N we have
$$
\int{ g_N(x) \, \, \lambda^2(dx)}
= \sum_{n = 1}^{N} { \int{ f_n(x) \, \, \lambda^2(dx)} }
$$ using the linearity of the integral.
As each $f_n$ is just a scaled indicator function we further get
$$
\int{ f_n(x) \, \, \lambda^2(dx)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \, \lambda^2(B_n)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \lambda^2( [−1/n^2,1/n^2) \times [−\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}) )\\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \, \lambda([−1/n^2,1/n^2) ) \, \lambda([−\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n})) \\
= \frac{2(1/n^2) \cdot 2\sqrt{n} }{\sqrt{n}}
= \frac{4}{n^2}.
$$

Summing up:
$$
\int{f(x) \, \, \lambda^2(dx)}
= \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} { \int{ f_n(x) \, \, \lambda^2(dx)} }
= 4 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}.
$$

For the value of this series see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem .

Comment: I see! If we take another set $A=\left \{ \left ( x,y \right )\in\mathbb{R}^2: u(x,y)=\infty \right \}$ would  the set be an element in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and that $\lambda^2(A)=0$? is $A=\emptyset$?

Comment: Is it on purpose that you use both $g$ and $f$?